# How do I check for existence of HTML elements and add text to it using CSS or Sass only?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I have two elements, author and citaion of  inside a div like follow:

```
<div>
   <h1>author</h1>
   <h1>citation</h1>
</div>
```

If both author and citation exist, I put a comma between author and citation. If only one of them exists or none of them exists,  I do not do anything.

Is there a way to do it in CSS or Sass only without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, you cannot manipulate an earlier sibling by checking the next one. The only way you can check if the second element is there and do something about it is selecting it.

You can solve it using pseudo-element `:before`. However, it may not be the way you want it because the two elements are on different lines (both `<h1>`).

So, if you want to make it without JavaScript, I would recommend to consider put both elements in the same line.

```css
h1 span:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: ', ';
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>author</span><span>citation</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: unless the `h1` are displayed inline then you can apply the same thing for the h1, this also works `h1 + h1::before`